# dump jquery object in an alert box

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, alert, dump

I am not quite adept in maneuvering jQuery, and it came to a point that I need to debug a program that was passed down from me without a documentation.

I have this var **a**, an object, that I really want to know the content of its collection. In my mind I need a function like `foreach()` in PHP to iterate over this object variable. Upon researching I end up in using [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/). Now I can clearly iterate and see what was inside var **a**.

However, it was kind of annoying to alert once every value on the var **a**. What I wanna know if it's possible to display all the contents in just one pop of alert box?

Here is my code:

```
$.each(a, function(index, value) { 
alert(index + ': ' + value); 
});
```

The var **a** contains infos such as:

```
creationdate: date_here
id: SWFUpload
modificationdate: date_here
type: .jpg
index: 0
name: uploaded_filename.jpg
size: size_in_bytes
```

BTW: The var **a** is called via file upload script.

Comment: you can use `stringfy` or `console.log()`

Comment: can you show us what `a` having??

Comment: As I state it is an object. Thanks for the consistent reply @diEcho.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Why don't you just accumulate the values in an array, then display the whole array (for instance, using JSON)? Example:

```
var acc = []
$.each(a, function(index, value) {
    acc.push(index + ': ' + value);
});
alert(JSON.stringify(acc));
```

In any case, I'd suggest using a debug tool like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/). So you could just use **console.log(a)** and be able to navigate freely through the objects's fields.

Comment: Great. As what I am looking for. Although the output was kind of gibberish to look at, still it's fine. Thanks!

Comment: It is hard to get the console, i.e. when you are debugging an iOS7 mobile application on real device, so this helps.

Answer (score 30):

In firefox you could try:

```
alert(yourObject.toSource());
```

OR you could use some plugin:
See: [jQuery Dump Plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-dump-plugin/)

Comment: Great suggestion regarding jQuery Dump Plugin.

Comment: Nice! I totally didn't know about `toSource()` in FF.  +1